# Loading module from file path with global variables

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.6

I want the user to be able to write their own minimalistic script files using some values as global variables.

Basically, I want something like this:
**bar.py** (same directory as main.py)

```
def bar(x):
    return f'bar({x})'
```

**foo.py** (possibly far from main.py)

```
b = bar('hi') #I want bar to be a global variable in this file
def foo(x):
    return f'{x}: foo({b})'
```

**main.py** (I used [Sebastian's answer on how to import modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path/67692#67692))

```
import importlib.util
from bar import bar

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("", r"/path/to/foo.py") #side question: does the name parameter have any effect on the code?
fooModule = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(fooModule) #<---somehow bring bar into foo's globals

print(fooModule.foo('kevin'))
```

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

EDIT: changed the requirements to ensure bar is global at load time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found out the answer. It's a bit wierd but you have to set bar as a value **between the loading and the excecution of foo**

**main.py**

```
import importlib.util
from bar import bar

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("", r"/path/to/foo.py")
fooModule = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
fooModule.bar = bar #<----
spec.loader.exec_module(fooModule)

print(fooModule.foo('kevin'))
```